# Set of all circles in cartesian plane without intersection is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove this problem:

> Prove the set of all circles in cartesian plane(Call that P) that they have not any intersection or none of them is in another one is **denumerable**.

[image]

And I must state that our coordinates is in R not Q!

For rational numbers we can denote a function such that all circles map to their center coordinates $(x,y)$ and radius$(z)$ so finally every circle will be mapped into $(x,y,z)$:$$f:P→ Q\times Q\times Q$$  $$f(c)=(x,y,z) ~~s.t~~c∈P$$
Its obvious that f is bijection.
So the function range is in $Q\times Q\times Q$.
And we know that $Q\times Q\times Q\sim N$.
So set of all circles with rational coordinates is denumerable and because we want no intersection , that is a subset of all circles and we know infinite subset of denumerable set is denumerable.

As you see I know how to prove it using **rational numbers** but for **real numbers** I have no any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be shown that for any circle $C$ there exists a point $A$ with rational coordinates (i.e. $A\in\mathbb{Q}^2$) lying inside $C$ (i.e. $A\in C$). Since the circles are disjunct such $A$ uniquely define $C$ inside which it lies. So, you can build an injection $P\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}^2$. Since $|\mathbb{Q^2}|=|\mathbb{N}|$ we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Since the rational numbers are dense in the real numbers, you should be able to choose an arbitrary rational number inside all of your circles and perform the same process. This method requires AC I think, but it should still work fine.

Comment: Could you please explain more and with mathematical signs?